# Java - store name field by using hashmap vs using seperate class

Tags: java

If I need to capture the name (first, middle and last) of a Person, I thought of the following possibilities:

1. Use a `Map<String, String>` name;
2. Use a separate Name class.

If I use a Map, I can store the names like this:

```
name.put("first", "xyz")
name.put("middle", "abc")
name.put("last", "nhf");
```

Then in the Person class:

```
class Person
{
   Map<String, String> name;
   //below write setter and getter for it.
}
```

If I use a Name class, I can store like this:

```
class Name
{
    String first;
    String middle;
    String last;
    //Below write setters and getters for them.
}
```

Then in the Person class:

```
class Person
{
   Name name;
   //below write setter and getter for it.
}
```

I wanted to know which one is a better way of doing and why. Also if there is any other better way of doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Map`s are great for flexibility. I.e., if you don't know exactly what keys you're going to have. E.g., if one person will have a Christian name, another will have a nickname and a third will have a paternal and maternal surnames, a `Map` may make sense. In your example, everybody has a first, middle and last name (although some of them may possibly be `null`?), so a map just adds redundant complication (as as noted here on the thread, memory consumption). Frankly, unless you have some special use for the entire `Name` as an object (e.g., using it as a key in a map), I'd just place three string members directly in the `Person` class.

Comment: I find your explanation convincing. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

This is entirely up to you -- there is no "best" answer here. It depends on how you are using the class.

Generally you do not want to hide things in a map like that. It makes more work to ensure things are correct. What if you accidentally add an incorrect key to the map? Your data structures could get out of whack easily with that method.

Personally, I would most likely just have the 3 values on the `Person` class directly and not bother with a `Name` class or a `Map`.

Once again, I am using words like "most likely" and "generally" because I do not know how the class is being used.

Answer (score 0):

Creating a map is quite memory consuming, compared to creating a name class.

It's better to create the name class, (for one thing, less lines of code :P), mainly because it's less prone to be changed mid-run, unlike the map.

The entries in a map might be accidentally changed during runtime, which could cause problems. If the Name class doesn't have setters, then this can't happen.